# Using .loc on DataFrame while ignoring several rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame that I need to modify based on one of column values. In particular, when the value in column `a` is above 110, I want the column `b` to be assigned value of -99. The only issue is that first 3 rows of the dataframe contain a mix of string and numerical data types so when I try:

```
df.loc[df['a'] >= 110, 'b'] = -99
```

I get a `TypeError` because comparison between `str` and `int` is not allowed.

So my question is: how do I do this assignment while ignoring the first 3 rows of the dataframe?

So far I came up with this rather dodgy way:

```
try:
    df.loc[df['a'] >= 110, 'b'] = -99
except TypeError:
    pass
```

This does seem to work, but it obviously doesn't seem like the proper way to do it.

EDIT: And also this method just skips first 3 rows, but I really need to keep them as is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

`df.loc[df['a'].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').ge(110), 'b'] = -99`

or use `errors='ignore'`

Comment: I want to keep the data in the top 3 rows as is. Wouldn't `apply(pd.to_numeric,errors='coerse')` replace the data with a bunch of `NaN`?

Comment: make a copy of the first 3 rows and re append after that operation

Comment: When I try to do it the way you suggested, I get a weird error: `ValueError: invalid error value specified`. Although it works if I do `errors='ignore'`